# React "FrebaseError: Function setDoc() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: a custom Map object"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-cloud-firestore

Description: I'm working on a React project where I'm trying to save the position of a user in a project saved in Firestore. The way I intended to do that is by saving a `positions` property, which is a Map of ProjectId and RoleId.

Here's the `IUser` model:

```
export interface IUser {
  firstname: string
  lastname: string
  email: string
  dateOfBirth: Timestamp
  middleName: string
  houseNumber?: string
  title?: string
  employer?: string
  positions: Map<string, string> //a map of project id and role id
  projectType?: string
}
```

And here's the method I used to create the firestore document:

```
protected updateCreateSingleDocument = <T>(
    url: string,
    id: string,
    data: T
  ): Promise<T> => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        const docRef = doc(collection(db, removeSpace(url)), id)
        await setDoc(docRef, data as any, {
          merge: true,
        })
        resolve(data)
      } catch (error) {
        reject(error)
      }
    })
  }
```

I've tested the user assigning modal, and here's the final `IUser` object I've gotten to be saved copied from the debug console.

```
{
    "firstname": "Alula",
    "middleName": "Abanega",
    "lastname": "Mono",
    "email": "elias@mail.com",
    "dateOfBirth": {
        "seconds": 1682553600,
        "nanoseconds": 0
    },
    "houseNumber": "124",
    "title": "Engineer",
    "employer": "Roma",
    "positions": Map(1),
    "projectType": "SUSTAINANCE"
}
```

And here's the `positions` map expanded, which has one element.

```
{
    "key": "PID_NEW",
    "value": "developer"
}
```

Problem: When I try to save this **User**, I keep getting "unsupported field value: a custom Map object" error. What am I doing wrong?

The services file I've created has been proved to work before the `Map` was added. I've gone over to [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types#:%7E:text=64%2Dbit%2C%20signed-,Map,-By%20keys%2C%20then) and seen that `Map<string, string>` is supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore can directly save a Map object in a document if the Map contains only primitive types like strings, numbers, booleans, and null. However, Firestore does not support Map objects containing nested objects or custom objects.

When you pass a Map to Firestore, it gets converted to an object literal with string keys and values, but the TypeScript compiler doesn't recognize this as a `Map<string, string>`.

For this to work you need to convert the `Map<string, string>()` to a plain object. You can do that using `Object.fromEntries()` method :

```js
const positions: Map<string, string> = new Map<string, string>();
positions.set("projectId", "value");

export interface IUser {
  firstname: string;
  lastname: string;
  email: string;
  dateOfBirth: Timestamp;
  middleName: string;
  houseNumber?: string;
  title?: string;
  employer?: string;
  positions: { [projectId: string]: string };
  projectType?: string;
}

const user: IUser = {
  firstname: "John",
  lastname: "Doe",
  email: "johndoe@example.com",
  dateOfBirth: Timestamp.fromDate(new Date("1980-01-01")),
  middleName: "A",
  positions: Object.fromEntries(positions),
};
```

Then you can add a user document through `setDoc()` like how you did.

Reference : [**Supported data types**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types)